# How can I stop event propagation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm submitting a form with jquery and can't seem to stop the page from reloading after the form submits.

My current code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" />
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Image Path</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="imagepath" id=imagepath />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <input type=button value="Send" id="sendemailbtn" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#sendemailbtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#basic_validate").submit();

    if ($("#basic_validate").children('.control-group').hasClass('error')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.post('send_email.php', $("#basic_validate").serialize(), function(data) {

            // I see output on the server side but never hit this area after the submission,

            console.log(data);
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#basic_validate").submit();
```

Is your culprit. That line submits the form and makes the page reload.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the page load?

Comment: If you omit that line (remove/comment out) and let your script continue. Try it out.

Comment: that won't work because I do some form validation on a form submisison

Comment: Do you need to submit the form to validate it? You have already catched the `click` event on `#sendemailbtn`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`submit` doc](http://api.jquery.com/submit/),

> [...] We can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on
>   the event object or by returning false from our handler.

As `.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to work for you, try :

```
$("#basic_validate").submit(function(){

    if ($("#basic_validate").children('.control-group').hasClass('error')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.post('send_email.php', $("#basic_validate").serialize(), function(data) {

        // I see output on the server side but never hit this area after the submission,

            console.log(data);
        }, "json");                             
    }            
    return false;  //This prevents reloading
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.submit()` works that way. If you want to submit the form with AJAX then you want to make an AJAX request manually with [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) without `.submit()`:

```
$("#sendemailbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$("#basic_validate").children('.control-group').hasClass('error')) {
        $.post('send_email.php', $("#basic_validate").serialize(),
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, "json");                             
    }    
});
```